# Sort Array By Object Property Percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I've got the following objects using AJAX and stored them in an array:[image]

How do I create a function to sort the objects by the PBE property in ascending or descending order using JavaScript

i am new to this javascript and tried like this

finalData.sort((a, b) => a.PBE < b.PBE ? - 1 : Number(a.PBE > b.PBE))

output: it sorts but not properly. Below is the out put from my console .

[image]

Comment: just use `finalData.sort((a,b) => a.PBE.match(/\d+/) < b.PBE.match(/\d+/))`

Comment: hmm no it does not sort the array of arrays

Comment: Why my question has 3 votes down. I tried all the options here.function generateSortFn(prop, reverse) {
    return function (a, b) {
        if (a[prop] < b[prop]) return reverse ? 1 : -1;
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) return reverse ? -1 : 1;
        return 0;
    };
}

Comment: a.PBE is a string. You can extract the numeric value from it. try `a.PBE.match(/\d+/)`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved finally just created a function like this and called the function like below

finalData.sort(generateSortFn('PBE', true));

```
function generateSortFn(prop, reverse) {
        return function (a, b) {
            if (parseInt(a[prop].slice(0, -1)) < parseInt(b[prop].slice(0, -1))) return reverse ? 1 : -1;
            if (parseInt(a[prop].slice(0, -1)) > parseInt(b[prop].slice(0, -1))) return reverse ? -1 : 1;
            return 0;
        };
    }
```